# heights of nested containers in css

Tags: html, css

bit confused about heights of nested containers in html/css.
for ex. in this case -http://jsfiddle.net/Y59a7/ if `inner2` and `inner1` have explicit
height 100%, then `height:100%` appears to work orelse it looks like the one in fiddle.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner1">
        <div class="inner2">
          <div class="inner3">
            asdlfalsjdflk
            asldkflaflkjkalf
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should include the css in the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to think of it:

`inner3` will have a height that's equal to 100% of the height of it's containing div (`inner2`).

But how does `inner2` calculate its height? As, in your example, `inner2` does not have an explicit height set, its height will be the minimum height required to display its content. (Taking padding and margins into account).

So `inner3` will have the height of `inner2`, and the height of `inner2` will be the natural height of `inner3`.

Comment: but then it requires user to add explicit heights to each nested container ? That's dull.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y59a7/1/)

```
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want inner3 takes up 100% of height, then all parents' height need to be set to 100%, even body and html